# Creating a function alias

Tags: c++, c++11, inline, stdbind

**EDIT:** This question was originally titled "Using `std::bind` to create inline function," but that's not really what I'm after: I just want a simple way to alias functions.

I would like to expose `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now` as a standalone function. That is, I would like to do the following:

```
auto current_time = std::bind(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now);
```

Unfortunately, since this is in a header file, it results in multiple definitions of `current_time` at link-time. Is there a way to return an *inline function* from `std::bind`?

Comment: What's wrong with `inline auto current_time() { return std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(); }`?

Comment: @T.C. Nothing in particular (it's what I'm using as a workaround), I just happen to think it's somewhat ugly. What I'd *really* like is function-aliasing, the way we have type-aliasing; i.e., `using current_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now;` would essentially behave like `#define current_time std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now` but without preprocessor involvement.

Comment: For the header you can always give it internal linkage.

Comment: @T.C. I may be misunderstanding you, but the point is to *expose* this function in multiple translation units--hence the need for `inline`.

Comment: Why does it need to be inline to use it in multiple translation units? Declare the function in the header, define it non-inline as a call to `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()`. Not sure why I'm even commenting on this ... just keeping using the function you already have (it's not a workaround, it's the solution).

Comment: @JonathanWakely It causes "multiple-definition" link errors if not inline.

Comment: Not if you declare a function and define it non-inline in one translation unit. Obviously if you have a function in a header and don't declare it inline, yes, you get multiple definitions ... so don't do that.

Comment: @JonathanWakely As pointed out in my comment to T.C., the whole point is to expose this as a utility function, which is why it's in a header in the first place.

Comment: That doesn't follow. You can **declare** a utility function in a header. That doesn't mean you have to **define** it in a header. Unless you have some peculiar definition of "utility function".

Comment: @JonathanWakely I would like the entire thing to be in the header, for two reasons: (1) it's just an alias, and this whole utility header is so simple that I have no reason to write a corresponding `cpp`. (2) The return type should be `auto`, because otherwise it's a horrible nightmarish line of text, and `auto` return types require either a `decltype` or a full definition.

Comment: OK, those are reasons to make it an inline function. T.C.'s first comment is still the best option, it is easier to understand and probably performs better than any of the answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's what I do if I want to create a simple function alias

```
constexpr auto &&now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now;
```

and if I want to create a full wrapper alias that will be inlined

```
template<typename ... Args>
inline constexpr auto now(Args &&... args) -> decltype(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(std::forward<Args>(args)...)){
    return std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

The reason why I use a universal reference `auto&&` in the alias definition is because of the possibility of `addressof(now) == addressof(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now)`.

On my system with G++ 4.9.2 running this:

```
constexpr auto &&now_ref = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now;
constexpr auto now_var = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now;

template<typename ... Args>
inline constexpr auto now_wrapper(Args &&... args)
    -> decltype(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(std::forward<Args>(args)...)){
    return std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    std::cout << std::hex << std::showbase;
    std::cout << (uintptr_t)std::addressof(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now) << '\n';
    std::cout << (uintptr_t)std::addressof(now_wrapper<>) << '\n';
    std::cout << (uintptr_t)std::addressof(now_var) << '\n';
    std::cout << (uintptr_t)std::addressof(now_ref) << '\n';
}
```

I get the following results:

```
0x4007c0
0x400a50
0x400ae8
0x4007c0
```

Showing that only the `auto&&` is actually a direct alias of the function, whereas all other methods have some level of indirection. (although, after compilation they *may* be replaced by inlined function calls. **maybe**.)

Comment: That *may* be inlined.

Comment: Interesting. Could you add a bit of explanation of why you use `static` and `&&`, since `constexpr auto` is sufficient to get this to work?

Comment: The `static` definition is so I don't run into multiple definition errors when defined in a header (a problem you ran into). The `auto&&` syntax is actually different to a regular type with `&&` after it, `auto&&` is actually somethin called a 'universal reference'. Ill leave that up to you to read about. If you use `constexpr auto` by itself you will prob'ly get a function pointer, but if you use `constexpr auto&&` you get a reference of the function such that `addressof(now) == addressof(chrono::high_resolution_clock::now)` as opposed to `now == addressof(chrono::high_resolution_clock::now)`

Comment: @NeilKirk if you really need it to be, you could add `[[always_inline]]` to the function definition (or the non-gcc equivalent)

Comment: @KyleStrand and because compilers are smart, the reference will be replaced by actual function calls in best-case-scenario (good optimization and such)

Comment: Good compilers can inline the first one, so the wrapper is overkill and doesn't add any extra guarantee of inlining.

Comment: @NeilKirk but that will only work in this case (non-templated, non-return-type-deduced, non-overloaded, simple function)

Comment: It's a good job the function is non-templated, non-return-type-decuded, non-overloaded and simple!

Comment: @NeilKirk otherwise I wouldn't have re-suggested the first idea ;) but it's good for OP to learn the second way for more special cases.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode `constexpr` implies inlining, so `static` is unnecessary.

Comment: Other than that, though, this is a really nice answer, though you should edit it to include the details you put in your comments.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is anyway to do this as bind is not constexpr.

Also lambdas are not constexpr-able.

Edit: there is this trick to make a constexpr-like lambda http://pfultz2.com/blog/2014/09/02/static-lambda/

Comment: That constexpr trick is insane and kind of awesome. Very much not what I was hoping for, though.

Answer (score 3):

Adding another answer 'cause it takes a very different tack to what you want.

std::bind isn't necessary in this case, because no 'binding' is happening.

However I feel this could lead to some confusing problems down the line, since current_time isn't really an alias in the same way that using delcarations are.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

auto constexpr current_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now;

int main() {
    auto now = current_time();
    cout << std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I get multiple-definition link errors when I use this approach.

Comment: You'd need to make  the `current_time` variable `static` or put it in an anonymous namespace. Declaring it const would work, as that makes it implicitly static.

Comment: As for using `bind`, I thought I saw a compile error at some point that indicated that `high_resolution_clock` is a member function, but on second thought that's  not actually the case, so you're right, `bind` doesn't seem to be the right approach, either.

Comment: `const` is a decent approach. Add it in your answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: On compilers that support it, this current_time should be able to be constexpr

Comment: @KyleStrand added constexpr

Comment: @tahsmith What are your thoughts on using a universal reference, as in CoffeeandCode's answer?

Answer (score 2):

Using GCC it is possible to create a "function alias", but only for functions which are defined in the same translation unit and for which you know the mangled name, so it's not possible to do reliably  for `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()`

See the `alias` attribute at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html

Comment: Interesting. A standardized/portable version of that would be quite nice.

Comment: No, it really wouldn't. The limitations on it are quite prohibitive. It's useful for compatibility kluges, e.g. to fix ABI mistakes in a library, not for general purpose utilities as you want.

Comment: Fine, then, a standardized/portable/less-prohibitive version would be quite nice!

Answer (score 2):

Keep it simple.

```
const auto current_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now;
```

Comment: I think tahsmith has dibs on that answer, but you do get an upvote.

Comment: @KyleStrand Doh too slow.